# Convert List into List of Lists that contain 10 items

Tags: java

I have a List of pojos. To convert this List of pojos into a List of List where each sublist is of the size 10 or less. So for example a List of size 13 is converted to a two element List. The first element is a List of 10 items, the second element is a List 3 items.

So the data structure is `List<List<pojo>>`

To create this List of lists :

```
List<List<pojo>> pojoList
counter = 0;
initialise new tempList
iterate list
add current pojo to temp list
if counter = 10 then add tempList to pojoList
reset counter and tempList and continue until list is iterated
```

Is there an alternative solution ?

Comment: Here are several interesting alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910236/how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-into-several-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

```
List<Pojo> originalList.... //your list of POJOs  
List<List<Pojo>> pojoList = new ArrayList<List<Pojo>>(originalList/10 + 1);  
for(int i = 0; i < originalList.size(); i+=10){  
    if(i + 10 > originalList.size()){  
         pojoList.add(originalList.subList(i, originalList.size()));
    }
    else{
         pojoList.add(originalList.subList(i, i + 10));  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider Guava's [Lists.partition()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

You still need to iterate but you are not going to need to create the `tempList`